# VERY confused - javascript not being executed - unless Console is turned on in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

I just started doing some Javascript work for a project, I do mostly backend work so I'm sorry for being new at this! Also, not using a Javascript framework because I want to learn about the fundamentals before making everything very easy for myself :)

So, here is my question/confusion: I wrote a little javascript that dynamically changed forms. This is how I called the code:

```
// loads the initial box
window.onload = initList(environment_box);

// loads artifacts on each change to environment select box
environment_box.onchange = changeList;
```

This worked like magic - in CHROME that is! I never noticed it wasn't working in Firefox (its just an internal tool, so I can assume decent browsers, but I figure hey, if its working in Chrome, it will work in Firefox!). So, I did some investigation, and it seems as though the code isnt getting executed in Firefox. I whipped out firebug and wanted to see what was going on.

The interesting thing was, when I enabled Console on firebug, my code got executed! I am very confused as to why, and I would much appreciate any help I could get. Thanks!

-Shawn

Comment: Try adding a simple `alert()` to your code to see if anything at all is being fired. You may have some intermittent issue in your functions causing the code to conditionally work/fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling some method on `console` in your JavaScript is my best guess. Chrome has `console` defined be default, so it is not a problem.

On Firefox, however, there is no such global object (not without Firebug), so when you try to call a property on an undefined object like,

```
console.log(..);
```

it throws an exception which you are not catching, so the JavaScript execution halts.

Comment: Wow. That could very will be it. A friend of mine just told me to use console.log because it was awesome, and it seemed so! I shall try this theory of yours right now!

Comment: It's best to define it yourselves if it's not already available. Ideally you wouldn't want console.* in a production app, but then again it's easy to change the behavior of a custom object to start sending logs/errors to a remote server with the flip of a switch. So console logs are good, but have a backup plan embedded in your scripts, or just overwrite the whole thing and in development mode send it to the native console (if exists), or remote server for production.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling a method of the console object which just doesn't exist by default in most web browsers. It may be always available on webkit based browsers (like Chrome) but with firefox/IE(/opera?) it requires an external add-on, either firebug or a javascript dependency.

Checkout things like [firebugx](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.2/lite/firebugx.js) which simply defines the most common methods of a console object as no-op functions.